# No supported authentification method when sending email

Tags: email, authentication, smtp, exchange-server, telnet

I tried to send an email using SMTP server but I couldn't. 
I am getting this message:

```
SMTP-AUTH: No mutually supported authentication methods available
Authentification Failed
```

So I connected to server using telnet.

```
telnet server 2526
ehlo server
250-server Hello [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
250-SIZE 36700160
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-AUTH
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250 CHUNKING
```

I think that the server is not configured well, because there isn't STARTTLS option (it's Microsoft Exchange server). I'm a bit confused, because there's AUTH optionm but I don't know what does it mean. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server's probably set up to not allow authentication.
Just try to send e-mail without any authentification e.g. using [sendEmail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/)

```
sendEmail.exe -f a@b.com -t b@c.com -u "SampleSubject" -m "SampleBody" -s smtp.xxx.com:25 -v
```

The authentification methods are defined in [RFC 4954](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4954#page-9)